# Find math formula to calculate stress on particular system?

Tags: arithmetic

I need help in knowing how to calculate "stress level" for the particular system. The data used by the sys is shown as picture.
[taxonomy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU0wu.png)

How will it works that each row will have a `sensitivity` score . For in the table red shows value of `8` out of `10`. The rest in white has default value which is `3`. Stress would be against the attributes mentioned under the `vulnerability` column of the table.

So if

```
Increase in stress-level = Sum of X attributes (sensitivity value score) -  total possible sensitivity value score
```

> <50% = 2
>
> >60% =3
>
> >90%=4

So, till the time the incident is in process and not closed be it `1` hour. I want the attribute e.g people to be effected based upon cal above.

So, after closure of incident after `x` hours the same attribute under vulnerability column is hit with corresponding value shown in red color in the taxonomy table I want to double the effect.

For e.g

> 90%=4 x 2

Please suggest, I'm open to reason.